# How to add multiple UIImageViews to a UIView; from a list of images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiimageview

I want to add multiple `UIImageView`s on top of eachother in a `UIView`.

I'm building a view then saving to library successfully. I add a pic from camera or library for background then add multiple images on top of it; from a `TableListController`.
On `viewDidLoad` I write every `UIImageView` for each available image; and view only appears on images user picks from `TableListController`.

This is a limited solution. When user picks same image; image is overwritten. I want to be able to duplicate images on the view.

I want to write a `UIImageView` for each image the user picks and have them stay on the view.

How to add multiple `UIImageViews` to `UIView`; from images picked from `TableListController`?

Here's what I have now. I need a more dynamic solution.

```
CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0,-20,320,480);
self.createView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
self.createView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.createView];

self.bgImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
self.bgImgView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
[self.createView addSubview:self.bgImgView];


NSData *imageDataz = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"catzero-item-0"];
UIImage *myPickZero = [UIImage imageWithData:imageDataz];
UIImageView *test0 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:(UIImage *)myPickZero];
test0.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
[self.createView addSubview:test0];

NSData *imageDatao = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"catzero-item-1"];
UIImage *myPickOne = [UIImage imageWithData:imageDatao];
UIImageView *test1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:(UIImage *)myPickOne];
test1.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
[self.createView addSubview:test1];
```

Comment: Put some code related to adding imageView on view.

Comment: I edited my original post; adding my limited current/working code.

Comment: Where are you showing these images? Is it in a table view? or normal UIView? Why dont you use a for loop to create UIImageView and add it to UIView subview then? And is it possible to use [UICollectionView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Comment: CreateViewController has a default `UIView`, then `viewDidLoad` draws createView(`UIView`), then I'm adding `UIImageView`s to createView.

Comment: You are messing with frames of imageViews you are adding on createView. All imageViews have same frame, thats why they are getting  overwritten

Comment: code is working fine. No image is getting overwritten in frames. When user picks an image from TableListController; it gets put in a UIImageView and ADDED to the UIView; where other UIImageViews are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do something more dynamic, you could do something like:

```
CGRect frame = self.view.bounds; // probably better to get the parent's bounds, rather than hardcoding frame dimensions

CGRect myFrame = frame;
myFrame.origin.y -= 20; // I'm not sure why you're offsetting this by 20, but you really do, grab the superview's bounds and offset it
self.createView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
self.createView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.createView];

self.bgImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
self.bgImgView.frame = frame;
[self.createView addSubview:self.bgImgView];

self.imageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger i = 0;
NSData *data;

while ((data = [userDefaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"catzero-item-%d", i++]]) != nil)
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = frame;
    [self.createView addSubview:imageView];
    [self.imageViews addObject:imageView];
}
```

This will read images for the keys prefixed by `@"catzero-item-"` and create image views for them. I'm also saving the individual `UIImageView` references into a `NSMutableArray` property that I've created, `imageViews`. Whether you do that is up to you.

Having said that, there are parts of your code I don't quite get: For example, every `UIImageView` has the same frame ... I don't know why you'd create image views that will be obscured by each other, but that's up to you.

I'd also not be inclined to store an array of images in `NSUserDefaults`, but that, again, is up to you. I'd probably be inclined to use `CoreData` or `SQLite` or a `plist` to store this array of images (or, more accurately, store the filenames there, and keep the images in the `Documents` folder). But using `NSUserDefaults` requires us to iterate through hypothetical key names, which is fragile (e.g. what if you have 3 images and then get rid of the second one ... are you going to rename all of the keys to avoid a gap in the key names). But if you use a `plist` or use `CoreData` or `SQLite`, you can iterate through a collection of images, without worrying about missing key names.

Anyway, hopefully this gives you ideas on how to retrieve images more dynamically.

Comment: -20 pixel offset is to correct an issue when saving to Library. I want to add images on top of a background and move those images around on top of background.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer to; how to add multiple UIImageViews to a UIView; from a list of images.

The code below is currently working in iOS6:

CreateViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "Item.h"
#import "PickTableViewController.h"
#import "CreateViewController.h"
@interface CreateViewController : UIViewController {
    CGPoint startLocation;
}


@property(nonatomic, strong)UIView *createView;
@property(nonatomic, strong)UIImageView *bgImgView;

@property(nonatomic, strong) Item *currentItem;
@property(nonatomic, strong)UIImage *myPick;
@property(nonatomic, strong)UIImage *myImage;

@property(nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *imageViews;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *imageViewItems;
```

CreateViewController.m

```
// create a view on top of base view controller.
CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0,-20,320,480);
self.createView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
[self.view addSubview:self.createView];
// This is an pic chosen by user from camera or library or default image.
self.bgImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[self.createView addSubview:self.bgImgView];

// currentItem is set in TableViewController and passed via prepareforsegue.
NSString *cat = currentItem.category;
NSString *file = currentItem.filename;

// add images to "imageViewItems" array.
imageViewItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
Item *img = [[Item alloc] init];
[img setCategory:cat];
[img setFilename:file];
[imageViewItems addObject:img];
img = [[Item alloc] init];
[img setFilename:@"catone-item-0.png"];
[imageViewItems addObject:img];
img = [[Item alloc] init];
[img setCategory:@"catone"];
[img setFilename:@"catone-item-1.png"];
[imageViewItems addObject:img];

// create array of uiimageviews from array of images.
CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
CGRect _myFrame = frame;
for (int i = 0; i < [imageViewItems count]; i++) {
    // get array item.
    Item *arrayItem = [imageViewItems objectAtIndex:i];
    // get filename from array item.
    NSString *curpick = arrayItem.filename;
    // create UIImage from array item filename.
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:curpick];

    // create UIImageView with UIImage
    ItemUIImageView *imageView = [[ItemUIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = _myFrame;
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    // add subview to createView.
    [self.createView addSubview:imageView];
    // add UIImageView to array.
    [self.imageViews addObject:imageView];
}
```

This is the subclass UIImageView file, referenced in CreateViewController.h and .m, for draggable images.

ItemUIImageView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ItemUIImageView : UIImageView {
    CGPoint startLocation;

}

@end
```

ItemUIImageView.m

```
#import "ItemUIImageView.h"

@implementation ItemUIImageView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code


}
return self;
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {

CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
startLocation = pt;
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
CGFloat dx = pt.x - startLocation.x;
CGFloat dy = pt.y - startLocation.y;
CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(self.center.x + dx, self.center.y + dy);
self.center = newCenter;
} 




@end
```

This file is custom class for storing image object info.

Item.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Item : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *filename;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *category;

@end
```

Item.m

```
#import "Item.h"

@implementation Item

@synthesize filename, category;

@end
```

Im not sure if I'm to answer my own question after Rob helped. I didn't find a complete example here at stack so here's mine.

Answer (score 0):

have look at the this [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MyImagePicker/Introduction/Intro.html).

from [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com)

It will help you a lot.